# If condition with externally selected value

Tags: counter, verilog

I'm new to Verilog and it is maybe a dumb question but what is the preferred codeflow in Verilog to solve this problem:

Simple counter, counting external clk (INP) up to a particular value. If the counter matches the value it rises an output wire (DRDY) for one clk period then lowers it to 0. There is an external input (SR) where I'd like to set the comparison value, so if SR = 0, then the counting is up to 500000, if SR = 1 then up to 1000000. I can do it with one value, but I'd like to expand the functionality of my module.

Thank you in advance.

My code so far with one value comparison:

```
module ec(INP, RST, SR, DRDY, DRDY2);

input INP, RST, SR;
output reg DRDY, DRDY2;

reg [23:0] Q;





always @(posedge INP or negedge RST)
begin
    if(!RST)
        begin
        Q <= 24'd0;
        DRDY <= 1'b0;
        end
    else if( Q == 24'd1000000) 
        begin
            Q <= 24'd0;
            DRDY <= 1'b1;
            DRDY2 <=~DRDY2;
        end             
    else
        begin   
        Q <= Q + 1;
        DRDY <= 1'b0;
        end
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to handle 2 options would be an expand the if statement:

```
always @(posedge INP or negedge RST) begin
  if(!RST) begin
    Q    <= 24'd0;
    DRDY <= 1'b0;
  end
  else if( 
    ( (SR ==1'b0) && (Q == 24'd1000000) ||
      (SR ==1'b1) && (Q == 24'd500000)
     ) begin
        //...
   end             
else begin   
  //..
end
```

This can look quite messy in the code so could be separated out into a count target logic, if more options are to be supported then switch to a case statement instead of if.

```
reg [23:0] cnt_target ;
always @* begin 
  if (SR == 1'b1) begin
    cnt_target = 24'd1000000 ;
  else begin
    cnt_target = 24'd500000  ;
  end
end

always @(posedge INP or negedge RST) begin
  if(!RST) begin
    Q    <= 24'd0;
    DRDY <= 1'b0;
  end
  else if( Q == cnt_target) begin
        //...
   end             
  else begin   
    //..
  end
```

NB: You might want to consider using `Q >= cnt_target` that way if SR changed on the fly you do not have to wait for Q to overflow. Plus `>=` for me tends to synthesis smaller than `==`.